# Expected hitting time of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

If I recall correctly, it is known that for a standard brownian motion starting at $0$, that the expected time to hit some level $a>0$ is infinite. I'm curious if there's a proof of what the expected hitting time is for an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

Let $\lambda >0$ and $X_t$ be the stochastic process which solves: $dX_t = -\lambda X_t dt + dW_t$. Let $\tau_a = \inf\left\lbrace t\geq 0: X_t = a >0\right\rbrace$. Assuming $X(0)=0$, is there a way to determine what the expected first hitting time should be? I would think it should also be infinite since the process $X_t$ drifts towards $0$ as it gets further away, so it should take longer to hit some level $a$, but I'm curious if there's a mathematical way to show this, or at least the idea of it.

Answer (score 3):

Set $f(x,t)=xe^{\lambda t}$. By application of Ito's lemma, we have
$$df(t,X_t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,X_t)dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,X_t)dX_t+\frac 12\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t,X_t)d[X_t,X_t]$$
therefore
$$df(X_te^{\lambda t})=\lambda X_te^{\lambda t}dt+e^{\lambda t}(-\lambda X_t dt+dW_t)$$
as a result

$$d(X_te^{\lambda t})=e^{\lambda t}dW_t$$
Since $X(0)=0$, thus
$$X_te^{\lambda t}=\int_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda s}dW_s$$
or
$$X_t=e^{-\lambda t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda s}dW_s$$
By the Dambis, Dubins-Schwartz theorem,there is a Brownian motion $B(t)$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda s}dW_s=B_{\tau(t)}$$
where
$$\tau(t)=\frac{1}{2\lambda}(e^{2\lambda t}-1)$$ Hence, the representation 
$$X_t=e^{-\lambda t}B_{\tau(t)}$$
holds, which is known as the Doob's transformation.The conditional probability
$$P(X_t\le x\,|\,X_0=0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma(t)}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma(t)}\right)du$$
where
$$\sigma(t)=e^{-2\lambda t}\tau(t)$$
tends to the standard normal distribution, of course, as $t\to \infty$ (meaning that transients die out with time and don’t affect long-term behavior). Therefore I think (if I am right) that the solution of any problem involving the OU process would be similarly straightforward. Anyway , [Thomas](http://Some%20mean%20first-passage%20time%20approximations%20for%20the%20Ornstein-%20Uhlenbeck%20process), [Ricciardi and Sato](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3214232?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) showed that
$$\mathbb{E}[\tau_a]=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{a}\left(1+\operatorname{erf}\left({\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)\right)\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)dt=\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}^na^n}{n!}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Hi, could you explain more about how to obtain $\tau(t)$? Many thank!